# Sparse linear solver in fortran working with REAL16

Tags: finite-element, numerics, fortran

I need some (direct) sparse linear solver for fortran, which works with REAL16 data type. Any suggestions? Both Pardiso and MUMPS support only REAL8. (identical question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016856/sparse-linear-solver-in-fortran-working-with-real16?noredirect=1#comment8293130_4016856)

Comment: Possibly of use to you https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/8204/19136

Comment: Do you need sparse LU or sparse Cholesky?

Comment: Cholesky is sufficient.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to convert a simple older code like YSMP.  I vaguely recall doing that back in the 90's.